# How can I investigate why my WLAN keeps reconnecting?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have problems with the wireless internet connection at work. At home it works fine, so I guess it is not my computer / hardware.

How can I investigate the problem? What are potential reasons for that?

The WiFi Works for colleagues - for some better, for some similarly bad.

### Additional Information

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Linux HP-EliteBook-1040 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$  cat /etc/issue                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 


$ sudo lshw -C network
[...]
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 3a
       serial: f4:8c:50:ab:7b:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-74-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.43.209 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:e1000000-e1001fff
```

Comment: 1. check the router log. 2. check /var/log/ for messages appearing when connecting drops. " At home it works fine, so I guess it is not my computer / hardware." be careful there. It can be your hardware: this can be a compatibility issue between the work-router and your system(s). The router log is the one to look for 1st. it will log notifications about a system getting dropped. The same should be visible in /var/log but those notifications tend to not show a reason.

Comment: Run the command `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to see logs